# Wordpress 3.6.1 menu not saving, server error with nav-menus.php

Tags: wordpress, menu

I can access the nav-menus.php page, and I can start to add or change menu items. It says: Click Save Menu to make pending menu items public. But when I go to save menu I get a 500 server error The website encountered an error while retrieving http:// w ww.....com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Reload this webpage.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Error code: 500 
I couldn't see any entry in /var/log/httpd/error_log but others due to spambots were coming up.

Before I was getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu_update_menu_items() in /home/christi/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php on line 349

I changed theme. No change. I disabled all plugins which is when I first found the message:

Before I was getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_nav_menu_update_menu_items() in /home/christi/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php on line 349

Before that I was getting the white screen of death when saving menus. Reactivating plugins caused all kinds of OTHER errors when WP_DEBUG was set to true.

My site works fine externally other than the fact I can't change my menus except my messing with the Database directly. Can anyone give me an easy path to getting this stable again? Is it best to downgrade to 3.6 since the problems only came up since upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to disactive all your plugins.